# Mean of total energy as sum of means

Tags: classical-mechanics, means

I have a question about the mean value of the total energy. I read that in the context of finding an adiabatic invariant for the pendulum 
\begin{equation}
E = \langle T + V \rangle = \langle T \rangle + \langle V \rangle 
\end{equation}
holds, with $E$ denoting the total energy, $T$ denoting kinetic energy and $V$ denoting potential energy. Which conditions are necessary that this is true, or is it valid in general?

Comment: This is valid in general. Whether $T$ and $V$ are independent or not, this always holds.

Comment: Why? Is it because of the sum rule for integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume by default a joint distribution $ f_{TV}(t,v) $. Then,
\begin{align}
  E(T + V) &= \int_t \int_v (t+v) f_{TV}(t,v) \, dv dt \\
  &= \int_t \int_v t f_{TV}(t,v) \, dv dt + \int_v \int_t v f_{TV}(t,v) \, dt dv \\
  &= \int_t t f_T (t) \, dt + \int_v v f_V (v) \, dv \\
  &= E(T) + E(V)
\end{align}